Mathematical Deduction theorem proof in the case where the induction fails (two-line deductions)
The mathematical induction theorem (the more challenging part) usually is stated like this (see e.g. the wikipedia page on the mathematical deduction theorem):
$$\Delta\cup\{A\}\vdash B\Rightarrow \Delta\vdash(A\rightarrow B)$$
where $\Delta$ is a (possibly empty) set of wffs, and A and B are wffs. We assume that you do NOT know a priori if A and/or B are axioms, and we do NOT assume
A = B and we do NOT assume that either A or B is in $\Delta$
Suppose the deduction from $\Delta\cup\{A\}$ to B has exactly two lines:

A
B

In this case the usual induction argument using MP cannot be used b/c MP requires at least three lines (a premise X, an implication X->Y, and then a deduction Y).
How can one conclude
$$\Delta\vdash (A\rightarrow B)$$
in this case where the starting deduction is the one above, where A is not nec. = B and A and  B are not necessarily axioms, and we do NOT assume that either A or B is in $\Delta$ and the deduction is just

A
B

Or can it be proved that such a two-step deduction cannot occur?
Completing this step would seemingly be crucial in bridging the gap in the usual induction proofs from the 1-line deductions to the n-line deductions. Those n-line deductions actually seem to implicitly assume n > 2 in order to use the MP argument.
Thanks to several people who responded to my question.
The answer is that the proposed deduction I asked about,

A
B

cannot be a deduction with the standard definition of deduction precisely b/c B is assume to be not an axiom, not a premise, and (b/c there are only two lines) not a consequence of MP.
So B cannot be legitimately 'deduced' from just A and the premises (and axioms).
